# C# ADO.NET Transaction Scope Auto Committed Before Calling Complete()

Tags: c#, .net, db2, ado.net, transactionscope

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(db2ConnectionString))
        {
            myCon.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand
                                   {
                                       CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                                       CommandText = insertQuery, // INSERT QUERY
                                       Connection = myCon
                                   };

            _ = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

1. Run the C# code with DB2 connection string
2. Before calling `scope.complete()` method, the inserted value is committed in DB2 and able to be seen by querying in the DB2 table
3. But the similar code for SQL connection works well